# Can I implement DataAnnotations to my Properties in a DTO class?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I wonder if my class' properties can include DataAnnotations as attributes and later being used in ASP MVC 4? This class is a part of WCF web service.
An example from the class UserAccount:

```
[DataMember]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50,
        ErrorMessage = "The number of characters is larger than the maximum allowed.(The maximum number of characters is 50)")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
```

and then in ASP.NET MVC 4 view:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)<br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
```

The thing is that I'm not getting the "Name is required" as error message when the input field is empty.
Here comes the controller for the view:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddUser(UserAccount uAccount)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }
        string a = string.Empty;
        smc.AddUserAccount(uAccount.Name,
            uAccount.LastName,
            uAccount.Address,
            uAccount.UserName,
            uAccount.UserMail,
            uAccount.Password,
            "admin");

        return Redirect("#");

    }
```

Is there something I've forgot in the indexController?

Comment: Maybe not an answer to your question I don't advise you to put Data Annotations on DTOs behind a service. Service do provide abstraction, which means they provide data to clients without knowing their platform (WinForms, MVC, Android etc.), programming language (C#, Java etc.). But when you provide Data Annotations on DTOs (which are behind a service) you provide this information to every client which might not be MVC applications. Of course there are workarounds you can use but it seems like a contradiction to the idea of data abstraction to me.

Comment: So many posts lately where people don't seem aware of auto properties: `public string Name { get; set; }`

Comment: @itsme86 I'm fully aware of auto properties. That's not the solution to my problem though.

Comment: @user3021830 Thanks for your input. It makes sense. What do you suggest? I was thinking of doing a "copy of" the DTO class in client side but that is just double work and not that productive.

Comment: I would suggest use of MetadataType attribute. But I have written a small application to simulate the use of it in a WCF/MVC project and unfortunately declaring the Data Annotations in the MVC project did not work. Although I believe that data annotations should be declared in the MVC project I can not suggest it since it did not work for me. May be further research on the subject might help. Sorry for not being able to come with a solid answer.

Comment: @Mnemonics If it was a solution I would have posted it as an answer. ;)

Comment: You need to invoke the controller's ValidateModel() method. See [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30912368/1577058).

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from ApiController

```
...
    
[ApiController]
class YourController : ControllerBase
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. In addition to the code snippet you provided, please can you explain how your solution solves the OP's question?