# Manually validate Model in Web api controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a class called 'User' and a property 'Name'

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And api controller method is

```
public IHttpActionResult PostUser()
{

       User u = new User();
       u.Name = null;

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

        return Ok(u);
}
```

How do i manually validate the User object so the ModelState.IsValid return false to me?

Comment: Why do you create the `User` object manually? If it was the model, the user would be an input parameter to the `PostUser` method. Do you want to know how to validate an arbitrary object against the rules specified by data annotations (e.g. `[Required]`)?

Comment: its just an example. I am following this toturial http://monox.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/233/Async-upload-using-angular-file-upload-directive-and-net-WebAPI-service/ to upload a file. and if u see here we got model data using var "fileUploadObj = GetFormData<UploadDataModel>(result);". I have created this question for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @MuzafarKhan Your simplified example breaks your question - your user should be a parameter if you want to validate it.

Comment: So we can't validate object manually ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [`Validate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.validate) method of the [ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller) class to manually validate the model and set the [ModelState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.modelstate).

```
public IHttpActionResult PostUser()
{
    User u = new User();
    u.Name = null;

    this.Validate(u);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    return Ok(u);
}
```

Comment: thanx...thats what i want :)

Comment: this.Validate(objectToValidate); it is all you need!

Comment: needs ModelState.Clear(); before Validate(u); also "this." is entirely pointless here

Answer (score 5):

This answer is not for this case, but it is very relevant if you want to validate a parameter manually:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(User user)
{
    ModelState.Clear(); // remove validation of 'user'
                        // validation is done automatically when the action
                        // starts the execution

    // apply some modifications ...

    Validate(user); // it adds new keys to 'ModelState', it does not update any keys

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this should be a comment on the accepted answer saying in some cases you might wish to clear the model state

Answer (score 3):

You will need to define custom Validation Attribute as

```
class CustomValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  //custom message in ctor
  public CustomValidator() : base("My custom message") {}
  public CustomValidator(string Message) : base(Message) {}
  public override bool IsValid(object value)
  {
     return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString());
  }
  //return a overriden ValidationResult
  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(Object value,ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
     if (IsValid(value)) return ValidationResult.Success;
     var message = "ohoh";
     return new ValidationResult(message);
  }
 }
```

likewise in your model class

```
public class User
{
  [Required]
  [CustomValidator("error")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The model should be an input parameter to your ActionMethod, and ModelState.IsValid will validate as per the attributes you set in the Model class, in this case as it is set [Required] it will be validated againg null values,

and if you just wish to manually check whether there is a value, you can check it directly.

```
if (user.Name == null) {
  return;
}
```