# Why is my manual model validation extremely slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to manually validate my model using ApiController's Validate() function.
Like here: [Manually validate Model in Web api controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908134/manually-validate-model-in-web-api-controller)

It ends up taking more than 90% of my cpu time (~90 seconds) and I'm only calling it a single time on an object of this class.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyClass = new HashSet<MyItem>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("IX_MyClass_Name", IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Update Date")]
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas why the performance is so bad?

edit: here is a the code I'm running on EF 6.2.0, .net 4.5.2

```
[Route]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Add(MyClassDTO myClassDTO)
{
    try
    {
         MyClass myClass = MyClassMapper.MapMyClass(myClassDTO, dbContext.ItemTypes.ToList());

         Validate(myClass);
         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             return BadRequest(ModelState);
         }
         else
         {
             dbContext.MyClasses.Add(myClass);
             dbContext.SaveChanges();
             MyClassDTO newDTO = MyClassMapper.MapDTO(myClass);
             return Created(newDTO);
         }
     }
     catch (DbUpdateException ex)
     {
        return Conflict();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please include the code that does the execution. See also how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Is that an entity you loaded from EF? Any chance you have `MyItem` entities which reference other entities, which reference other entities  etc until you load all database in memory for validation?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes. That is what is happening. Anyway to limit it?

Comment: You should show the relevant code where you get and validate the entity. Also specify EF version you are using

Comment: This Q cannot be answered in the current state, as "slow" is subective and the shown solution includes multiple behind-the-scenes actions (mappings, database calls). Reduction to minimal reproducible case will most likely answer the question.